# Cordova Plugin downloading always on Build and Run

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am new in Cordova and IONIC framework, Whenever I build or run the cordova application, this cordova plugin is always getting cloned/downloaded from git-

```
ionic-plugins-keyboard
```

[image]

I mean every time on each build, here is the full list of cordova plugins which are listed in the config.xml file, no other plugin gets cloned but only this one.

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="^1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-extension" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="com.synconset.imagepicker" spec="https://github.com/startapplabs/cordova-imagePicker.git" />
    <plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" spec="^4.3.19" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="com.rjfun.cordova.iad" spec="^2.0.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" spec="^2.8.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git" />
    <plugin name="org.pushandplay.cordova.apprate" spec="^1.1.7" />
    <plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" spec="https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git" />
    <plugin name="com.ionic.keyboard" spec="https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^2.1.0" />
```

Comment: Anyone out there with something on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue.
Cordova also uses a `/plugins/fetch.json` file to control whether or not the plugins are already downloaded. 
You probably have this plugin declared only in your `config.xml`.
Removing and adding the plugin using the cordova cli should fix the problem (should automatically add it to `plugins/fetch.json`)

```
cordova plugin rm <problematic_plugin>
cordova plugin add <problematic_plugin>
```

Also the [ionic keyboard plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard)'s id is actually `ionic-plugin-keyboard`. You should change it in your `config.xml` (removing the `com.ionic.keyboard` entry and adding it using the cli as mentioned above is a better option as it will add the plugin from the `npm registry` instead of getting it from the git repository).

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I had resolved this issue like you mentioned above had forgotten to update this question with the answer but you answered, so accepting your answer.